# How to convert obfuscated AAR to Dex?

Tags: android, obfuscation, dex

I create an AAR and extract it then I convert classes.jar to dex file by this :

```
C:\Users\ms\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.3>dx --dex  --output classes.dex classes.jar
```

But after that I create an obfuscate AAR and extract it, When I tried convert classes.jar to dex file, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\ms\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.3>dx --dex  --output classed.dex classes.jar
no classfiles specified
```

What's the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the proguard-rules.pro file was empty.